# PHP count JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, http-post

I have searched SO but couldn't find an answer.My PHP script is receiving some JSON by http post that looks like this:

```
{
"task": [
{
  "task_id": "3",
  "task_due": "Oct 26 11:25",
  "task_completed": "FALSE",
  "task_desc": "fff",
  "task_time": "20131026_112531",
  "task_name": "fff"
},
{
  "task_id": "2",
  "task_due": "Oct 26 11:25",
  "task_completed": "FALSE",
  "task_desc": "rff",
  "task_time": "20131026_112522",
  "task_name": "xff"
},
{
  "task_id": "1",
  "task_due": "Oct 26 11:25",
  "task_completed": "FALSE",
  "task_desc": "fggg",
  "task_time": "20131026_112516",
  "task_name": "ff"
  }
 ]}
```

As you can see, there are 3 items, but when I turn it into a PHP array object and count the items, I'm returned 1, when it should be 3, here is my PHP code:

```
$json_tasks = $_POST["json_array"];
$task_array = json_decode($json_tasks,true);
echo count($task_array);
```

And `echo count` prints out '1' not '3'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `echo count($task_array['task']);`

In general, if you wonder what the structure of the value of a variable `$var` is, do a

```
<pre><?php var_export($var, true); ?></pre>
```

Advantage of this function over alternatives such as `serialize` and `print_r` is, that it prints PHP code (and is thus readable by anyone who understands PHP (which is likely if you program in PHP)). Disadvantage of `var_export` is, that it cannot handle circular structures (e.g. if `$a->b == $a`), but neither can JSON.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, one more promblem when theres only 1 task, not 3, it says there are 6 tasks

Comment: You are interpreting the data structure incorrectly. Did you try my hint about `var_export`?

Answer (score 5):

Well the `3` items are in `1` item `"task"` so, you have one array named task and the 3 elements are in it

try

```
echo count($task_array['task']);
```

**EDIT :**

please use the below code to print the array in correct pattern

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($task_array['task']);
exit();
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, one more promblem when theres only 1 task, not 3, it says there are 6 tasks

Comment: @Coder101 well just look at your array, there is one array **task** in which there are 3 arrays and then in each of there 3 arrays there are 6 elements

Answer (score 5):

```
$task_array = json_decode($json_tasks);
count($task_array->task);
```

EX: 3

From Taiwan

Answer (score 1):

try this code, here i can able to count the number of objects with specific value

here's my data.json file content

```
{"likes":[
    {"user_id":1,"time":"12:04pm"},
    {"user_id":2,"time":"02:04pm"},
    {"user_id":67,"time":"11:04pm"},
    {"user_id":1,"time":"12:04pm"}
]}
```

here's the php code

```
<?php
$jsonData = file_get_contents("data.json");
$data = json_decode($jsonData,true);
$total = 0;
foreach ($data["likes"] as $value) {
    if($value["user_id"]==1){
        $total = $total+1;
    }
}
echo $total;
?>
```

output will be

```
2
```