# Count JSON values with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON and I want to count how many times `id_pieasa` appears with same value and how many time `garantie_piesa` is true or false for that `id_piesa` also the sum of `cantitate_piesa`
Here is the JSON I have:

```
[
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"7",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"18",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"313",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"312",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"68",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"44",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"168",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":true
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"444",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"91",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"168",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"44",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"308",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"1",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"27",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"26",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"65",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"74",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":true
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"82",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"120",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"120",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":true
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"71",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"168",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"44",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"91",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"444",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      }
   ]
]
```

for example: id_piesa 168 appears 2 times sum cantitate_piesa is 2 and 1 time is true 1 time is false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP count JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606094/php-count-json-array)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a JSON based question with an invalid JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Ive used json formater to get a valid json array https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ Then you can try this:

```
//decode json array We receive multidimensional array
$t = json_decode('[
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"7",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"18",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"313",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"312",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"68",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"44",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"168",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":true
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"444",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"91",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"168",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"44",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"308",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"1",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"27",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"26",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"65",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"74",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":true
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"82",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"120",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"120",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":true
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"71",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id_piesa":"168",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"44",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"91",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      },
      {
         "id_piesa":"444",
         "cantitate_piesa":1,
         "garantie_piesa":false
      }
   ]
]',true);

//This will be our new array with statistic data
$newArr = [];

//Looping arrays
foreach($t as $s) {
  foreach($s as $arr) {
      // We'll use id_piesa for keys in our $newArr, here we check if record
      // with this key exists in the new array 
      if(!array_key_exists($arr['id_piesa'], $newArr))
      {
         // if not create new record and assign cantitate_piesa
         $newArr[$arr['id_piesa']] = [
           'id' => $arr['id_piesa'],
            'cantitate_piesa_sum' => (int)$arr['cantitate_piesa']          
         ];
         // check if garantie_piesa is TRUE or FALSE and count that 
         // for this record
         if($arr['garantie_piesa'] == true) {
           $newArr[$arr['id_piesa']]['countTrue'] = 1;         
         } else {
           $newArr[$arr['id_piesa']]['countFalse'] = 1;
         }
       } else {
         // record exists so just add to it cantitate_piesa
         // from array being looped
         $newArr[$arr['id_piesa']]['cantitate_piesa_sum'] = 
         $newArr[$arr['id_piesa']]['cantitate_piesa_sum'] + (int)$arr['cantitate_piesa'];
         // again check if garantie_piesa is TRUE or FALSE and count that 
         // for this record
         if($arr['garantie_piesa'] == true) {
            $newArr[$arr['id_piesa']]['countTrue'] = $newArr[$arr['id_piesa']]['countTrue']+1;
         } else {
           $newArr[$arr['id_piesa']]['countFalse'] = $newArr[$arr['id_piesa']]['countFalse']+1;
           }
        }    
    }
}

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($newArr);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

This may help (example on a small Php array, you'll need to decode your json and deal in similar manner):

```
<?php

$data =
[
    ['id'=>4,'amount'=>2],
    ['id'=>4,'amount'=>3],
    ['id'=>5,'amount'=>5]
];

foreach($data as $item) {
    $ids_amounts[$item['id']][] = $item['amount'];
}

$ids_freqs       = array_map('count',     $ids_amounts);
$ids_sum_amounts = array_map('array_sum', $ids_amounts);

var_dump($ids_amounts);
var_dump($ids_freqs);
var_dump($ids_sum_amounts);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
  }
}
array(2) {
  [4]=>
  int(2)
  [5]=>
  int(1)
}
array(2) {
  [4]=>
  int(5)
  [5]=>
  int(5)
}
```